# Save Image dataset into CSV

Tags: python, export-to-csv

I have an Image dataset consisting of 90k images of size [64,64,3].
I have done some preprocessing to the images, which takes a lot of time if I have to do it from scratch.
Now, how do I store these images/ images as a numpy array for shape[90000,64,64,3] into a csv file, as integers, along with their labels?

Is there any other way (other file type) to store this data?

P.S: I tried np.savetxt but, when I read back the data, I get strings with dots and a lot of the values are lost.

Thank you.

Comment: Please show the code you have tried up until now

Comment: If you just want to reuse the object, you should use pickle to directly dump the python object to disk. It is not time-efficient nor space-efficient to save the string literals of the array in a csv file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it!!

We can use

```py
np.save()
```

to save the array in a .npy format and load the file using

```
np.load()
```

Also, multiple numpy arrays can be saved using

```
np.savez()
```

and

```
np.savez_compressed()
```

to save them in .npz and a compressed .npz format.
COOL